# Sub using super's instance method on its own field members

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Suppose i have the classes `SUPER` and `SUB` where `SUB` extends `SUPER`. Both are concrete classes.

There is an instance method, say `m1()` of `SUPER`. `SUPER` does some basic calculations using the field members in that method `m1()`. 
`SUB` wants to use those `SUPER` is doing on its own field members-- and add some more on top of it.

When i'm overriding `m1()` in `SUB`, I first can invoke 
`super.m1()`. However, this invocation runs `super.m1()` on the field members of the object of `SUPER`-- not `SUB`. What i need is, `super.m1()` running on `SUB`'s members so that i don't have to repeat that code in the method i'm overriding. Then add more-- those further calculations that i want to do on `SUB`'s members in the `m1()` method of  `SUB`.

So - in the code below, i'm looking to get the effect of calculation in "line-K" on the member `x` of some so that the printed result will show 661 instead of 67:

```
class AAA  {    
    int x=55;
    void m1 () { 
        x*=10; // line-K
//        System.out.println("in m1() of SUPER "+x); 
    } 
}

class NewClass extends AAA  {
    int x = 66; 
    void m1 () {
        super.m1(); 
        x++; 
        System.out.println("in m1() of SUB itself..............."+x); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        NewClass c = new NewClass();        
        c.m1();
    }
}
```

Can this be done by overriding `m1()` in some way without repeating that code in `super.m1()`?

How?

TIA.

//=========================================

EDIT:

I can pass `x` as a parameter to the method and get it returned-- by making `m1()` take a param & return a value, thus get done what I need. But that's not what i'm wondering about.

Comment: You should write out example code to demonstrate this. As it is now it is a bit hard to visualize.

Comment: will get back w/the code.

Comment: Do you mean you're redeclaring fields in SUB to hide those in SUPER? I'd stop doing that, to start with...

Comment: I smell some code issues if you are needing to do what you want it seems like either your classes need to be different and the are loose connect and you are forcing a connect between them Or what you want is to keep the attribute only in parent and not in child...

Comment: Hiding instance variables in subclasses is really bad code smell.  Please explain the underlying objective trying to accomplish by doing this and maybe we can suggest a different way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of declaring a member in subclass with the same name as a member in the superclass is called [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3).

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the
>   declaration of that field **is said to hide** any and all accessible
>   declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and
>   superinterfaces of the class.

(There is hiding for methods and for fields.)

Fields are not polymorphic. In this case, the super class does not know about the member declared in the sub class and it definitely should not. That would break encapsulation.

> Can this be done by overriding `m1()` in some way without repeating that code in `super.m1()`?

No. The solution you've proposed with an extra parameter seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the standard way to get what you want:

```
static class AAA  {    
    int x=55;
    void m1 () { 
        setX(getX()*10); // line-K
    } 
    int getX() { return this.x; }
    void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
}

static class NewClass extends AAA  {
    int x = 66; 
    void m1 () {
        super.m1(); 
        setX(getX()+1); 
        System.out.println("in m1() of SUB itself..............."+getX()); 
    } 
    @Override
    int getX() { return this.x; }
    @Override
    void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }

}     
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NewClass c = new NewClass();        
    c.m1();
}
```

Instance variables are not virtual but methods are.

HOWEVER, hiding instance variables in a subclass is almost never a good idea.